# What is a Linux device name for RAID of sas drives?

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, sas, device, smartctl

I have a RAID1 using Promise FastTrack TX2650 consisting of 2 SAS drives. What is a Linux device name for them? Like `sda` is for first sata drive. I have Windows server so I can't look it directly but need this information for `smartctl` usage.

UPDATE. I found how to access RAID: `smartctl -d scsi sdb` (because I also have a SATA drive). But in this case I just get an information about just raid controller though I wantto get information about drives itself. Is it possible? Promises's control panel provides information only about their healthy status (boolean) and I want more. Mostly now I need information about temperature.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect new information. In short, you're probably not going to be able to use smartmontools for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer:

Okay, after you clarified what you were looking for, here's what I have to say. It sounds like you have the Promise RAID controller set up to present the two drives as a single array to the operating system. This being the case, the drives are completely abstracted from the OS, and the OS has no way of getting the "raw" access to them that it would need to extract the SMART data.

You'll need to rely on whatever tools Promise has to report on and monitor the health of its array members.

Old answer:
I assume this is a "real" hardware RAID controller? If so, then yes, the array should show up as /dev/sdX, where X=a,b,c,etc. If you want to check for sure, burn a Knoppix live CD, boot off of it, and see what the array is detected as. Once booted, you should be able to parse through the output of `$ dmesg` to see what device type it was detected as.

I'm still confused, though, why you need this information to use smartctl on a windows server. Perhaps you could clarify that so we can make sure to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Yes, it's a real PCI-express RAID controller.

To get info from smartctl I need to provide a drive name because a command's syntax is `smartctl -a DEVICE_NAME` as far as I understand. Possibly you would advice other software to get info from smart (not just a health status provided by controller's control panel). Mostly I need temperature.


I'm not able to run live cd due to physical inability to access cd-rom on that computer.

Comment: Understood. Even though smartctl is, by its pedigree, a *nix based tool, that doesn't mean that you'll need to pass a linux device name to it when running in windows. Windows won't know what to do with `/dev/sda`. You need to figure out what format the windows version of smartmontools is expecting for device names. If it follows cygwin's pattern, the device name will be something like `/cygdrive/c` or `/cygdrive/d`, depending on what the windows drive letter is for that array.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and comments. I take your new answer. BTW, smartctl under windows uses linux naming, such as `sda`. It works as I checked on SATA drive installed in the server.

Answer (score 1):

In recent kernels ( > 2.6 ) pretty much all hard drives and hardware RAID devices appear as /dev/sd#

If the Promise FastTrack is presenting one logical drive (as in, it's performing the RAID0 or RAID1), then check /dev/sd#

You should be able to find it by issuing 'dmesg'

Comment: I have windows, not linux so I'm not able to run `dmesg`. I found how to access the raid controller itself(yes, it is `sd#`) but not a drives (see update of the post).